# Execute 2 python scripts simultaneously using Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I have 2 python scripts that I want to execute at the same time using Jenkins, however every method I have tried executes the first one and waits for it to finish in order to start the next. Does anyone have a solution for this? Another option is to maybe make 2 builds in jenkins and have the 2nd one start building a minute or so after the first, but I am not sure how to do that either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Parallel Stage by using pipelines. This way you can run your scripts in the same time.

You can check this for more details.
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it worked well, but ultimately went with Multijob plugin